# Regular expression replace with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line, sed

I'm making replacments in PHP file and I need to change the language variable with sed. Here my WORKING code:

```
sed -i '' -e "s/\$config\['language'\]  = \"english\";/\$config['language'] = '$LANGUAGE';/" Sources/$APP/application/config/config.php
```

This is not working to match any language set:

```
sed -i '' -e "s/\$config\['language'\]  = \"*\";/\$config['language'] = '$LANGUAGE';/" Sources/$APP/application/config/config.php
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sed`, the asterisk (`*`) character denotes "repeat the previous thing 0 or more times." This is in contrast to a shell, where it expands to anything. What you want to do is shove a `.` (which means "anything"), right before the asterisk, like so:

```
sed -i '' -e "s/\$config\['language'\]  = \".*\";/\$config['language'] = '$LANGUAGE';/" Sources/$APP/application/config/config.php
```

That will then tell your program "repeat any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`)".

Answer (score 1):

That's because `*` doesn't do what you think it does. In a `sed` regular expression, as in all regular expressions, use `.*?` to mean any collection of characters (except newlines). That is because `.` means match anything once and `*` means match the previous item any number of times. The `?` makes it non-greedy, meaning it will match as few characters as possible as long as the rest of the expression matches. I don't know what you input is so I can't tell if you need the question mark, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `*` in the expression with `.*`.  `*` means "0 or more instances of the previous item" (in this case the `"`), so you want to first match `.` (any character), then state you want 0 or more instances of *that*.